# How to edit custom menu widget CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, widget

I want to create a horizontal custom menu in wordpress. I've added a custom menu widget to the footer of my site (not online yet) but it displays a vertical bullet list menu. Where can I change that?

I'm using latest wordpress and the [Interio theme](http://themeforest.net/item/interio-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/4616897) if that helps any.

I don't know how to edit CSS for custom menu widgets. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using this [dropdown menu widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/) which can also be set to create horizontal menu's :)

Comment: Will this plugin helps to create sidebar menus?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the CSS for any widget in your theme's `style.css` file.  Using your development tool of choice (Chrome dev tools or Firebug), inspect the menu widget (the vertical bullet list menu) and see if you can identify any unique but consistent selectors for that menu.  Those will be the selectors you'll use to target this menu and style to your liking.

Have fun!

Comment: Strange that there is no option in WP to set the custom menu to horizontal by default.. The CSS is a mess, I can't find where to add display: inline so it will show horizontal :(